# listview in Fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

Something wrong the XML,Please correct me and thank you in advance, below is the code?

Sorry i don't speak english 100/100.

```
public class Les_agences
    extends Fragment {
        /* ****************************************** */
        /*              Les Variables                */
        /* ****************************************** */

    public String string_ip = "192.168.42.168";
    public Resources res;
    public JSONObject json;
    public ListView les_agence_tete_lsiteview;
    public TextView les_agence_tv_item_adresse;
    public TextView les_agence_tv_item_nom;
    public ImageView les_agences_iv_item_image;
    public ListView liste_view;
    ArrayList<item_Les_agences_liste_view> liste;
    item_Les_agences_liste_view item;
    JSONArray jsonoarray = null;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            /* pour creer le fragment*/
        les_agence_tv_item_adresse = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.les_agence_tv_item_adresse);
        les_agence_tv_item_nom = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.les_agence_tv_item_adresse);
        les_agences_iv_item_image = (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.les_agences_iv_item_image);
        View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.les_agences, container, false);
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        res = getResources();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        connecter();
    }

    void connecter() {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {
            ProgressDialog progress;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progress = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), res.getString(R.string.act2_connexion), res.getString(R.string.act2_attendre), false, false);
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                thread processus = new thread();
                processus.setPaire(null);
                processus.seturl("http://" + string_ip + "/agence_de_location/les_agences.php");
                processus.start();
                try {
                    processus.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
                json = processus.getJson();
                if (json == null) {
                    return (false);
                } else {
                    return (true);
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                progress.dismiss();
                if (result == false) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), res.getString(R.string.act2_erreur_connexion), 10000).show();
                } else {
                    int val = 0;
                    try {
                        val = json.getInt("val");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if (val == 0) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), res.getString(R.string.act2_erreur_connexion), 10000).show();
                    } else {
                        /******************************************************** */
                                /*              Pour afficher les agences                 */
                        /******************************************************** */
                        // pour afficher    
                        liste = new ArrayList<item_Les_agences_liste_view>();
                        try {
                            jsonoarray = (JSONArray) json.get("agence");
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                        }
                                    /* Yes return les champs  */
                        int indice;
                        item_Les_agences_liste_view item;
                        for (indice = 0; indice <= jsonoarray.length() - 1; indice++) {

                                        /* new array , grand array agence 0 : 1 : 2 : ... 
                                         *petit array 0: .... 
                                         */
                            JSONObject petitearray = null;
                            try {
                                petitearray = jsonoarray.getJSONObject(indice);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                                        /* catch entre new class */
                            try {
                                Log.i(petitearray.getString("nom_agence"), petitearray.getString("nom_agence"));
                                item = new item_Les_agences_liste_view(petitearray.getString("nom_agence"), petitearray.getString("adresse_agence"), petitearray.getString("image_agence"));
                                liste.add(item);
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                liste_view = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.Les_agences_lv);
                Adapter_les_agences_list_view adapter = new Adapter_les_agences_list_view(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), liste);
                liste_view.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        }.execute();
    }
    /******************************************************** */
        /*              class adapter                             */

    /**
     * *****************************************************
     */

    class Adapter_les_agences_list_view
        extends ArrayAdapter<item_Les_agences_liste_view> {

        private Context context;
        private ArrayList<item_Les_agences_liste_view> liste;

        public Adapter_les_agences_list_view(Context context, ArrayList<item_Les_agences_liste_view> liste) {
            super(context, R.layout.les_agences_liste_view, liste);
            this.context = context;
            this.liste = liste;
        }

        // le nombre des élements de la lsite 
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return liste.size();  // nmbre des element 
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View new_place = convertView;
            if (convertView == null)//adapter le 1er fois s 
            {
                // style
                LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                View rowView = li.inflate(R.layout.les_agences_liste_view, null);
            }
            les_agence_tv_item_adresse = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.les_agence_tv_item_adresse);
            les_agence_tv_item_nom = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.les_agence_tv_item_adresse);
            //les_agences_iv_item_image=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.les_agences_iv_item_image);
            return convertView;
        }
    }
}
```

the file of network is true .

```
public class Menu
    extends FragmentActivity {
    private ViewPager menu_viewpager;
    private android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter pageradapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        menu_viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.menu_viewpager);
        pageradapter = new Adapter_menu(getSupportFragmentManager());
        menu_viewpager.setAdapter(pageradapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        le_swap();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        TextView les_agence_tv_item_adresse = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.les_agence_tv_item_adresse);
        TextView les_agence_tv_item_nom = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.les_agence_tv_item_adresse);
        ImageView les_agences_iv_item_image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.les_agences_iv_item_image);
        les_agences_iv_item_image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(Menu.this, "ss", 1000);
            }
        });
    }

    void le_swap() {
    }
}
```

the menu , main of programm

the menu , main of programm

```
package PFD.agence_d_allocation;

import PFD.agence_d_allocation.R.string;
import android.R.integer;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Event;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.internal.view.SupportMenu;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewDebug.IntToString;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.widget.ViewFlipper;
public class Menu extends FragmentActivity  {
    private ViewPager menu_viewpager ; 
    private android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter pageradapter;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);

        menu_viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.menu_viewpager);
        pageradapter = new Adapter_menu(getSupportFragmentManager());
        menu_viewpager.setAdapter(pageradapter);


    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        le_swap();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();



    }




    void le_swap()
    {

    }








}
```

the log cat

```
05-09 11:40:06.158: D/dalvikvm(544): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 3% free 10326K/10631K, paused 41ms
05-09 11:40:06.348: D/AndroidRuntime(544): Shutting down VM
05-09 11:40:06.348: W/dalvikvm(544): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
05-09 11:40:06.408: I/dalvikvm(544): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544): java.lang.NullPointerException
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at PFD.agence_d_allocation.Les_agences$1.onPreExecute(Les_agences.java:94)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:561)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:511)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at PFD.agence_d_allocation.Les_agences.connecter(Les_agences.java:204)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at PFD.agence_d_allocation.Les_agences.onCreateView(Les_agences.java:56)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1072)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:918)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1440)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:812)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1369)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:660)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:553)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4698)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2092)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12723)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
05-09 11:40:06.459: E/AndroidRuntime(544):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-09 11:40:06.478: I/dalvikvm(544): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-09 11:40:06.768: D/dalvikvm(544): GC_CONCURRENT freed 159K, 3% free 10645K/10951K, paused 39ms+24ms
05-09 11:40:06.909: I/dalvikvm(544): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-09 11:40:06.918: I/dalvikvm(544): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
05-09 11:40:07.189: I/dalvikvm(544): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
05-09 11:40:07.218: I/dalvikvm(544): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: you get android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Comment: the Networkmain True 100/100

Comment: please use https://translate.google.com/ I don't understand you

Comment: Brahimce i'm trying to help you but i don't understand you

Comment: if there is an error, you need to specify where the error is, or show the stacktrace (logcat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `onCreateView`, you have first to inflate your main layout and then find his subviews (childs) referring to it with `name_of_your_view.findViewById()`. Now you are using activity context to inflate something that is inside your fragment layout:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /* pour creer le fragment*/
    View x = inflater.inflate(R.layout.les_agences, container, false);
    les_agence_tv_item_adresse = (TextView) x.findViewById(R.id.les_agence_tv_item_adresse);
    les_agence_tv_item_nom = (TextView) x.findViewById(R.id.les_agence_tv_item_adresse);
    les_agences_iv_item_image = (ImageView) x.findViewById(R.id.les_agences_iv_item_image);
    return x;
}
```

Comment: @Brahimce so post the stacktrace

Comment: Same problemf  @Fondesa

Comment: @Brahimce Post the logcat